# How to use UDF function on the pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas data frame I need to apply the clean rule on the name column so that the name only consists of the string value, not the numerical value but I need to do that using a UDF. SO I have created a UDF and then applied it on the name column of my data frame but I am not getting the desired result.
Sharing some screenshots of my code and the output.
Please, anyone, guide me once.
[This image is my code screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vdnQ.png)

Comment: Please share your code and data as text so that it is easier to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Mortz I have given my code snippet and the data that I am having is sample data so the data frame consists of only 3 entries which you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: Please include any code and errors as formatted text not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify `remove_num` function, then it will work.

```
import re
def remove_num(emp_name):
    remove_val = re.sub("[0-9]", "", emp_name)
    return remove_val
```